# Corrupted images when using Read and Write streams to save files

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, httpclient, filestream

Hello fellow programmers

I'm implementing a download feature in an app using Xamarin (iOS), to get a progress on the files it is downloading.

The code I use is various examples from all around the web, showing the same principal, with the biggest difference in coding style. They all use the same ReadAsync and WriteAsync functions on System.IO.File, with a byte-array as buffer.

But no matter what example I turn to, it results in the pictures getting different artifacts on them, like this:

[image]
[image]

(Original / Downloaded)

I can't seem to find any reason why this happens.
I've tried out different things to see what could trigger this. I found that changing the buffer to a larger size (say 10240) results in more artifacts, and a smaller buffer (say 1024) results in less artifacts.

When debugging different things, I found a "way" to "avoid" this from happening, but that includes adding a Task Delay right after the WriteAsync just finished, for 20 milliseconds (commented out in the code) - Not a solution I wanna go with, but tells the issue may lay in the usage of the two streams (in witch my knowledge is 'basic usage only').
I also tried to use the non-async methods, but gives the same result.

Hope someone can tell me what I did wrong here, and why.

Thanks in advance

```cs
public async Task<bool> MakeDownloadRequestAsync(string url, string destination, Action<string, long, long, float> progress = null) {
    if (_downloadHttpClient == null) {
        _downloadHttpClient = new HttpClient (new NativeMessageHandler());
    }

    bool finished = false;

    try {
        var result = await _downloadHttpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

        long receivedBytes = 0;
        long totalBytes = result.Content.Headers.ContentLength.HasValue ? result.Content.Headers.ContentLength.Value : 0;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("Started download file: {0}", url);

        using (var stream = await _downloadHttpClient.GetStreamAsync (url))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            var filename = Path.GetFileName (url);
            var writeStream = _fileStore.OpenWrite (Path.Combine(destination, filename));

            while(true)
            {
                int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    finished = true;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("Finished downloading file: {0}", url);
                    break;
                }


                await writeStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                //Task.Delay(20);
                receivedBytes += bytesRead;

                if (progress != null)
                {
                    progress.Invoke(url, receivedBytes, totalBytes, (float)receivedBytes/(float)totalBytes);
                }
            }

            writeStream.Dispose();
            stream.Dispose();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (e);
    }


    return finished;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the exact image file before and after the operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is probably this line:

```
await writeStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

It should be:

```
await writeStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

Your code is writing the entire buffer...regardless of how many bytes were actually read.  Instead, you should only write the number of bytes that were actually read.

Comment: Of course, that makes so much sense. I expected the buffer length to change depended on it's content, but that will be a fixed size (as I asked it to be). Thanks a million Doug!

Comment: Glad to help Pelle.  It's a common mistake.  If I may make another comment, the stream.Dispose() call is not needed.  When you use the using statement, the Dispose is called automatically.

Comment: I'm aware of the double stream.Dispose(), was another failed attempt to see what could fix the problem. But thanks for putting it to my attention :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what is wrong with the above source code. But I have a snippet to download files and save which works for me perfectly.

```
public async static Task DownloadByteArray(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler())) 
    {
        try
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri (url))) 
            {
                using (var responseContent = response.Content) 
                {
                    var byteArray = await responseContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    var folderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Downloads");
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (folderPath);

                    var extension = url.Split ('.').Last ();
                    string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine (folderPath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")+"."+ extension);
                    File.WriteAllBytes (filename,byteArray);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I will explain if you have any further doubts in this snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is a download to a byte-array in memory. The files I may download may be larger than the available memory. Also doesn't give me the progress of the file currently being downloading.